# Como converter decimal para binário com números grandes?

Tags: c#, .net, string, biginteger

Estou criando um programa em linguagem C# para realizar conversões no momento estou implementando o binário -> decimal e decimal -> binário.

Como posso fazer a conversão se o usuário digitar números grandes como devo tratar isso?

#### Botões

```
private void Btn_Decimal_Binario_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                //Armazena o valor em decimal, convertendo o texto em tipo inteiro
                int ValorDecimal = int.Parse(txt_decimal.Text);

                //Realiza a chamada do metodo e armazena resultado na textbox
                txtBinario.Text = DecimalParaBinario(ValorDecimal);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Verifique o preenchimento das informações no formulario ! ", "Alerta !", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            }
        }

        private void Btn_Binario_Decimal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                //Armazena o valor em binario,convertendo o texto em tipo inteiro
                int ValorBinario = int.Parse(txt_Binario_2.Text);

                //Realiza a chamada do metodo e armazena resultado na textbox
                txt_decimal_2.Text = BinarioParaDecimal(ValorBinario);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Verifique o preenchimento das informações no formulario ! ", "Alerta !", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            }
        }
```

**Conversões**

```
static string DecimalParaBinario(int n)  
        {
            int resto;
            string result = string.Empty;
            while (n > 0)
            {
                resto = n % 2;
                n /= 2;
                result = resto.ToString() + result;
            }

            return result.ToString();
        }

        static string BinarioParaDecimal(int n)  
        {
            //Conversão Binario em Decimal
            int bin, dec = 0, resto, basenum = 1;
            bin = n;
            while (n > 0)
            {
                resto = n % 10;
                dec = dec + resto * basenum;
                basenum = basenum * 2;
                n = n / 10;
            }
            return dec.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: O que é "números grandes"?

Comment: Como vc deve tratar ? declare uma variável de numero grande.. porque vc declara  `int `  para ValorDecimal???? não é um valor  Valor  `Decimal `

Comment: Olá @MatheusGonçalves seja bem vindo ao StackOverflow. Poderia nos dar um exemplo desses "números grande"?

Comment: Por exemplo mesmo colocando em Decimal se eu digitar por exemplo 1231231231231231231231231232312312312 ele lança erro

Comment: @MatheusGonçalves Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 2):

Se realmente precisa disto, mude o tipo do número para [`BigInteger`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0).

```
static string DecimalParaBinario(BigInteger n) {
    BigInteger resto;
    var result = "";
    while (n > 0) {
        resto = n % 2;
        n /= 2;
        result = resto.ToString() + result;
    }
    return result.ToString();
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/5POdTs). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/rdYWZG). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conversion/Dec2Bin.cs).

A conversão inversa está totalmente errada.